# JavaScript - Share value between function callbacks

Tags: javascript, callback, bind

I have a function `foo(a, b, c)` from an external JavaScript library.

`a`,`b`, and `c` are callback functions.

In callback `a`, i am generating a random ID `var id` that i use to reference a dom node with the `id` attribute. Is it possible to acces `id` from the callback function `c` ?

The callback `c` is normally called after `a` in the `foo` function.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes you can do that. Just declare `id` outside `foo`.

Comment: Sure, just defined `id` in a scope accessible by `a` and `c`. Closures ftw.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers. Could you share an example of closures ? I am not cumfortable with this.

Comment: @wI2L http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/H9CDw/

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 I think my need would be something like that instead: http://jsfiddle.net/d4Uz2/
Maybe my question wasn't clear. Anyway i tried this method, and i got "id is not defined". I'll try to create a more complex JSFiddle to be more clear.

Comment: @wI2L - Your example isn't working is because `a` is never executed.

Comment: I don't know what `_.bind` is, but in the example I gave you, there is only one `id`. It is not copied. In fact, all your callbacks can access the variable because `id` is "above" the callback functions.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Ok then i think i was wrong in my original question, because i need the value of `id` to be unique and non-shared between the instances of `c` callback.

Comment: @wI2L: Every invocation of `bar()` creates a new `id` variable and new callbacks. Your comment sounded like you are referring to the callbacks `a` and `c`, not `c`s from multiple invocations of `bar`. I guess it's time to read up on scope in JS :)

Answer (score 1):

You should not define id on a global scope, because foo might be called multiple times. Try something like this:

```
var that = {'that' : this, 'id': 42};
foo(a.bind(that), b.bind(that), c.bind(that) );
```

Then all functions a, b, c should be able to read/write via this.id
Full example:

```
<html><body>
<div id="log"></div>
<script>    
function Go(iCall)
{
    var that = {'that' : this, 'id': -1, 'call' : iCall};
    foo(a.bind(that), b.bind(that), c.bind(that) );
}
function foo(a,b,c)
{
    window.setTimeout(a,Math.random()*3000);
    window.setTimeout(b,Math.random()*3000);
    window.setTimeout(c,Math.random()*3000);
}
function a(){
    if (this.id < 0) this.id = 1;
    Log("a",this.call,this.id);
}
function b(){
    if (this.id < 0) this.id = 2;
    Log("b",this.call,this.id);
}
function c(){
    if (this.id < 0) this.id = 3;
    Log("c",this.call,this.id);
}
function Log(abc,call,id){
    document.getElementById("log").innerHTML += "<br/>"+Array(call).join("___")+" :Go("+call + "): "+abc+"() Id=" + id;
}

Go(1);Go(2);Go(3);
</script>
</body></html>
```

see in action: https://jsfiddle.net/vw35bz3d/